# Prometheus x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, black-box-testing, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I was trying to monitor one of our webservices by using Prometheus but I faced some problem for some our endpoints.

my prometheus.yml

```
job_name: 'blackbox'
metrics_path: /probe
params:
  module: [http_2xx_example]
static_configs:
  - targets:
    # Target to probe with https.
    - https://test-services.xxxxx.com/ 
    - https://test-services1.ffe.yy.com/
    - https://test-services2.ffe.yy.com/ 
    - http://test-services3.xxxxx.com/ 
tls_config:
  insecure_skip_verify: true
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: __param_target
  - source_labels: [__param_target]
    target_label: instance
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: xx:xx:xx:xx:9115  # The blackbox exporter's real hostname:port.
```

Although we don't have any problem with https://test-services1.ffe.yy.com/ and https://test-services2.ffe.yy.com/, but ı have problem with - https://test-services.xxxxx.com/  and  http://test-services3.xxxxx.com/.

it’s showing some error like –

/prometheus: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, Prometheus service is UP and also able to monitor some of the http requests.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segment

```
tls_config:
  insecure_skip_verify: true
```

from config you provided in question is responsible for configuration of tls between prometheus and blackbox_exporter.

Your error on the other hand occurs on connection between blackbox_exporter and target services. Check blackbox exporter's configuration: most likely list of CAs there out of date.

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved the problem thanks to your advice and information that gave me

Answer (score 0):

Check certificates within the container are not outdated. A temporary solution if that is the case is to map the host certificates to the container ones (/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).